# Database connectivity issue of Mule application with mysql database in linux environment

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, mule

I am trying to run a ETL mule application in Linux environment, While this application is running successfully in Windows Environment, while running in linux environment i am getting below exception. plz help

```
 org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.  at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:181)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:261)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:110)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:287)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:148)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
                at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52)
                at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)








    )Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
            at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:113)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't find the MYSQL connector. Add MYSQL connector properly in build path.

Check your host.